# Plugin to show how far users are reading?

Tags: statistics

I have plugins to count users per post per day, but i don't have any idea how far the users are actually reading.  Are there any plugins that can show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Google Analytics available, you can try out the [WP Scroll Depth plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scroll-depth/)